# Domain Control Validation via HTTP with Angular4 server

Tags: angular, ssl, server

I have website I am using `ng serve` to serve to my domain name, and I'm wanting install an SSL certificate for it, preferably without having to use other server technologies (at least for the moment). However, as Angular doesn't seem to have a root directory in the conventional sense I am uncertain where to correctly place the DCV file. Does it just go in the same directory as index.html, in the assets directory or somewhere else?

I'm using the latest version of Angular and the site structure was originally generated with angular-cli 1.1.0.